# RegEx that finds multiple lines that have same starting and ending pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net

I keep seeing solutions for Regexes that find lines/words with a start and end pattern but the difference is their patterns are different.

My dilemma is finding lines that have the same ending and start pattern.

Example:

```
** Hello, My name is
Name: enter**
```

That would result to one match. However when I do

Example:

```
 **Hello, My name is
 Name: enter**
 **Designation is:
 Field work**
```

The match result should be two, but catches three, which are:

```
 **Hello, My name is
 Name: enter**
```

And:

```
             **
**
```

And:

```
**Designation is:
Field work**
```

I'm using this Regex:

```
"^##.*##"
```

Someone said it is not possible using Regex, is this true?

Comment: Is the data in exactly this format where you have text spanned over multiple lines and you are trying to identify a line based on the ** characters... ie your data could span several physical lines but it is one virtual line between a set of ** ....... ** entries ??

Comment: @JacquesRamsden: Yes, it should be read as one whole line spanning in multiple lines.

Comment: @vks: Thanks! Awesome site, just what I needed. I did a little tweaking and added RegexOptions.Multilines and got what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: If you think any of the answers where right/helpful why not vote them up?

Comment: @JacquesRamsden: I would but sadly I don't have enough reputation, but I did pick vks' answer as he was the first one to answer. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: 100s I voted up Ahosan Karim Asik's answer as it was the most informative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\*\*[\s\S]*?\*\*)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/12

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**  `/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/s`

```
\*\* #match the first ** 
(.+?) # match any char btween ** and **  and group 
\*\*  #match the last ** 
s  #single line modifier.
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV7xS8/1)**

[VB demo](http://goo.gl/VfsJlz)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Regex

```
(\*\*(.*?)\\*\*\*)
```